Extrinsic matrices of sensors from tf_static_publisher
I have two lidar sensors, and an IMU, I also have the nodes of static_transfrom_publisher with the parameters in the standard format of:
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 link1_parent link1 100" />

However, I am using an odometry package that requires the extrinsic to be in format like:
extrinsic_T: [ 0.215, 0, 0.018, 
               -1.2574, 0.413, 0.0324,
               -1.306, -0.361, 0.042  ]

extrinsic_R: [ 1, 0, 0, 0,
               0.765018, -0.0017329, -0.0038405, 0.417535, 
               0.0014645, 0.0000044, -0.0003919, -0.999972]

Although, I understand rotation and translation matrices operations in general, I still find it hard to formulate such matrices given the values specified in the tf_static_transform_publisher format.
I would be really grateful if someone can explain me how does that work, what is the general rule of thumb to formulate extrinsic matrices from x y z roll pitch yaw or x y z qx qy qz qw, what are the elements of extrinsic_T and extrinsic_R and how do we get them?
